2nd Euler-Lagrange equation trivially zero?
I'm doing a course in Analytical Mechanics. We were introduced to variational calculus, and one of the exercises involved finding the trajectory of light in a medium where the speed is proportional to the $y$ coordinate. So by Fermat's principle I have to minimize:
$$
\Delta t = \int_{s_1}^{s_2} \text d s\ \frac{\sqrt{x'(s)^2+y'(s)^2}}{\alpha y}.\tag{1}
$$
This is easy to solve assuming one variable is a function of the other and using either the conservation of the "conjugate momentum" or "Hamiltonian", and indeed it does give the expected answer (circles). However, I wanted to try solving it directly without making that assumption, since in a more general case I don't think it's valid.
The calculations get a lot more complicated obviously, but since the partial $x$ derivative is zero,
$$
\frac{\partial f }{\partial x'}=\frac{x'}{\alpha y \sqrt{x'^2+y'^2} } = c \text{ (constant)}.
$$
From there,
$$
x' = \pm\frac{c\alpha y y'}{\sqrt{1-c^2\alpha^2y^2}}
$$
and
$$
x'' = \mp \frac{c\alpha\left(-y'^2+y(-1+c^2\alpha^2y^2)y''\right)}{(1-c^2 \alpha ^2y^2)^{3/2}}.
$$
The Euler-Lagrange equation for the other variable ends up being:
$$
\frac{  x'\left( x'^3-yy'x''+x'(y'^2+yy'') \right) }{\alpha y \sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}=0.
$$
Now replacing $x'$ and $x''$, being careful to use consistent signs, everything cancels out and I get $0=0$. Why does this happen and what does it mean?
I don't think I made a computation mistake, the only thing I think I might have gotten wrong is the ambiguous sign in $x'$, but using either case I get the same thing. By the way, I also noticed the Hamiltonian is identically 0 (maybe undefined?) too, which I also can't interpret.
My other guess is that the function is a total derivative with respect to the parameter. But in that case, how would I solve the problem without extra assumptions? Did I do something wrong?

Are circles the only solutions to the problem? $y(s)=Ae^{\alpha s};x(s)=B$ are solutions. Maybe it is necessary to check the uniqueness of solutions.

That's a good point. The exercise said to check that the solutions are circles so I assumed that was it. However the problem is that I find no solutions at all doing it this way.

The solution provided by Rafa doesn't work, because it doesn't solve the first equation of motion. Circles are indeed solutions (see my answer below).

Note that the left-hand side of your first Euler-Lagrange equation can be rewritten as a derivative :
$$
\dot{x} = \pm\frac{c\alpha y\dot{y}}{\sqrt{1-c^2\alpha^2y^2}} = \mp\frac{1}{c\alpha} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s} \sqrt{1-c^2\alpha^2y^2},
$$
Now, it can be integrated by seperation of the variables, hence $c^2\alpha^2(x-x_0)^2 + c^2\alpha^2y^2 = 1$, with $x_0$ another constant of integration. Clearly, it represents a circle of radius $R = \frac{1}{|c\alpha|}$ centered at $(x_0,0)$, as you wanted to check.
Beside that, a zero Hamiltonian means simply that the variables (and their respective momenta) don't evolve, meaning here that $x$ and $y$ are constant while lying on the aforementioned circle. Depending on the considered context, it could betray an unphysical or ill-defined model.

This really clears everything up! So the second equation ends up being redundant and that's why it becomes trivial when substituting the first. That should've given me a hint that it was enough to solve the first equation only. Which makes sense, given that the answer should depend on only one of the variables. Thank you very much!

FWIW, OP's "action" functional (1) has a "time" reparametrization gauge symmetry $s\longrightarrow s^{\prime}=f(s)$. As a consequence, the "Hamiltonian"  vanishes identically, cf. e.g. this & this Phys.SE posts.
This also means that there are effectively not 2 dynamically variables $x$ and $y$ but only 1. E.g. locally (away from vertical motion), one can impose a gauge-fixing condition $s=x$. Thus there is really only 1 independent EL equation.
(BTW, if the denominator in OP's "Lagrangian" (1) had had a square root, this would have been the brachistochrone problem with cycloid solutions instead of circles.)
